# Useful Command-line Commands on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

The aim for this Wiki is to promote using a command to open up commonly used applications without having to go through many mouse clicks - thus saving time on monitoring and troubleshooting Windows machines.

Answer entries need to specify

- Application name
- Commands
- Screenshot (Optional)

Shortcut to commands

- [&&](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6628#6628) - Command Chaining
- [%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\rcimlby.exe -LaunchRA](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/5101#5101) - Remote Assistance (Windows XP)
- [appwiz.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3787#3787) - Programs and Features (Formerly Known as "Add or Remove Programs")
- [appwiz.cpl @,2](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3959#3959) - Turn Windows Features On and Off (Add/Remove Windows Components pane)
- [arp](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/29672#29672) - Displays and modifies the IP-to-Physical address translation tables used by address resolution protocol (ARP)
- [at](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/33330#33330) - Schedule tasks either locally or remotely without using Scheduled Tasks
- [bootsect.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/21944#21944) - [Updates the master boot code for hard disk partitions to switch between BOOTMGR and NTLDR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177(WS.10).aspx)
- [cacls](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/20468#20468) - Change Access Control List (ACL) permissions on a directory, its subcontents, or files
- [calc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/5269#5269) - Calculator
- [chkdsk](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/23993#23993) - Check/Fix the disk surface for physical errors or bad sectors
- [cipher](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/13204#13204) - Displays or alters the encryption of directories [files] on NTFS partitions
- [cleanmgr.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3922#3922) - Disk Cleanup
- [clip](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/32955#32955) - Redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard
- [cls](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6627#6627) - clear the command line screen
- [cmd /k](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/5106#5106) - Run command with command extensions enabled
- [color](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6912#6912) - Sets the default console foreground and background colors in console
- [command.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/12734#12734) - Default Operating System Shell
- [compmgmt.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3791#3791) - Computer Management
- [control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3803#3803) - Network and Sharing Center
- [control keyboard](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3800#3800) - Keyboard Properties
- [control mouse(or main.cpl)](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3799#3799) - Mouse Properties
- [control sysdm.cpl,@0,3](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/5104#5104) - Advanced Tab of the System Properties dialog
- [control userpasswords2](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3891#3891) - Opens the classic User Accounts dialog
- [desk.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3874#3874) - opens the display properties
- [devmgmt.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3793#3793) - Device Manager
- [diskmgmt.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3795#3795) - Disk Management
- [diskpart](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/21936#21936) - [Disk management from the command line](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415)
- [dsa.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/23272#23272) - Opens active directory users and computers
- [dsquery](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4582#4582) - Finds any objects in the directory according to criteria
- [dxdiag](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/20418#20418) - DirectX Diagnostic Tool
- [eventvwr](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4083#4083) - Windows Event Log (Event Viewer)
- [explorer .](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3898#3898) - Open explorer with the current folder selected.
- [explorer /e](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3898#3898), . - Open explorer, with folder tree, with current folder selected.
- [F7](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/31200#31200) - View command history
- [find](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/27233#27233) - Searches for a text string in a file or files
- [findstr](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4861#4861) - Find a string in a file
- [firewall.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6339#6339) - Opens the Windows Firewall settings
- [fsmgmt.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4031#4031) - Shared Folders
- [fsutil](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4997#4997) - Perform tasks related to FAT and NTFS file systems
- [ftp](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/21967#21967) - Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
- [getmac](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3864#3864) - Shows the mac address(es) of your network adapter(s)
- [gpedit.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/11962#11962) - Group Policy Editor
- [gpresult](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows/59902#59902) - Displays the Resultant Set of Policy (RSoP) information for a target user and computer
- [httpcfg.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/15438#15438) - [HTTP Configuration Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787508.aspx)
- [iisreset](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4027#4027) - To restart IIS
- [InetMgr.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3796#3796) - Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager 7
- [InetMgr6.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3796#3796) - Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager 6
- [intl.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3808#3808) - Regional and Language Options
- [ipconfig](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6902#6902) - Internet protocol configuration
- [lusrmgr.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3977#3977) - Local Users and Groups Administrator
- [msconfig](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6822#6822) - System Configuration
- [notepad](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4025#4025) - Notepad? ;)
- [mmsys.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4422#4422) - Sound/Recording/Playback properties
- [mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/35208#35208) - Configure system devices
- [more](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/19077#19077) - [Displays one screen of output at a time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490933.aspx)
- [mrt](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6305#6305) - Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool
- [mstsc.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3784#3784) - Remote Desktop Connection
- [nbstat](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/19077#19077) - displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP connections using NBT
- [ncpa.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4421#4421) - Network Connections
- [netsh](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/21908#21908) - [Display or modify the network configuration of a computer that is currently running](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true)
- [netstat](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/19077#19077) - Network Statistics
- [net statistics](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6372#6372) - Check computer up time
- [net stop](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/19077#19077) - [Stops a running service.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490715.aspx)
- [net use](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/19110#19110) - Connects a computer to or disconnects a computer from a shared resource,  displays information about computer connections, or mounts a local share with different privileges [(documentation)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx)
- [odbcad32.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3797#3797) - ODBC Data Source Administrator
- [pathping](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/8759#8759) - A traceroute that collects detailed packet loss stats
- [perfmon](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows/64873#64873) - Opens Reliability and Performance Monitor
- [ping](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/25339#25339) - Determine whether a remote computer is accessible over the network
- [powercfg.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/12725#12725) - Power management control panel applet
- [qfecheck](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows/125941#125941) - Shows installed Hotfixes applied to the server/workstation.
- [quser](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4203#4203) - Display information about user sessions on a terminal server
- [qwinsta](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6522#6522) - See disconnected remote desktop sessions
- [reg.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/11244#11244) - Console Registry Tool for Windows
- [regedit](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3900#3900) - Registry Editor
- [rasdial](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4480#4480) - Connects to a VPN or a dialup network
- [robocopy](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4546#4546) - Backup/Restore/Copy large amounts of files reliably
- [rsop.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/7598#7598) - Resultant Set of Policy (shows the combined effect of all group policies active on the current system/login)
- [runas](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/19829#19829) - Run specific tools and programs with different permissions than the user's current logon provides
- [sc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6351#6351) - Manage anything you want to do with services.
- [schtasks](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/11548#11548) - Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system.
- [secpol.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3845#3845) - Local Security Settings
- [services.msc](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3786#3786) - Services control panel
- [set](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6741#6741) - Displays, sets, or removes cmd.exe environment variables.
- [set DIRCMD](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/16022#16022) - [Preset dir parameter in cmd.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773112.aspx)
- [start](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/13100#13100) - Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command
- [start.](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3962#3962) - opens the current directory in the Windows Explorer.
- [shutdown.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4987#4987) - Shutdown or Reboot a local/remote machine
- [subst.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6923#6923) - Associates a path with a drive letter, including local drives
- [systeminfo](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6516#6516) -Displays a comprehensive information about the system
- [taskkill](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6349#6349) - terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name
- [tasklist.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/5002#5002) - List Processes on local or a remote machine
- [taskmgr.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3817#3817) - Task Manager
- [telephon.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4426#4426) - Telephone and Modem properties
- [timedate.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4428#4428) - Date and Time
- [title](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6468#6468) - Change the title of the CMD window you have open
- [tracert](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/6901#6901) - Trace route
- [whoami /all](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows/123091#123091) - Display Current User/Group/Privilege Information
- [wmic](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/32530#32530) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line
- [winver.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4847#4847) - Find Windows Version
- [wscui.cpl](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4431#4431) - Windows Security Center
- [wuauclt.exe](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/25318#25318) - [Windows Update AutoUpdate Client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720477.aspx)

Comment: If you find this stuff interesting, take a look at commandlinefu: http://www.commandlinefu.com/ It's basically like digg for CLI

Comment: great list, very usefull

Comment: Try putting each command as a separate answer.  Then we can vote and comment on each one.

Comment: This is a great question, super useful info, and the stackexchange engine made it trivial to find.  I agree with @lamcro, however, that structuring each command as an individual answer would likely provide more value, however then the wouldn't be sorted alphabetically? hmmm...

Comment: @David Alpert: Yes, since answers cannot be sorted according to commands, that was why I was listing the command in alphabetical order in the question.  I wonder if grouping those commands would be even more useful or not.

Comment: This is a great example, across all SE, of a well-executed poll. I especially like combining separate answers (for voting) and alphabetical index to them!

Answer (score 120):

A little known one is

```
getmac
```

It shows the [MAC address(es)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of your network adapter(s).

[image: Screenshot of running getmac from a Windows commandline window.]

Comment: Very nice. When I run this on my laptop I get "ERROR: Not found.", however I can run getmac /? and it prints out the description / usage... ideas?

Comment: ipconfig /all gives you this information in a less direct way too.

Comment: Ha, now I've got your MAC address, prepare to be hackzored!

Comment: THANK YOU! No more ipconfig /all and scrolling around! "Happy dance!"

Answer (score 65):

In the command prompt type:

```
C:\> start .
```

It opens the current directory in the Windows Explorer.

Comment: How neat.  it works just like "ii ." in powershell.

Comment: start . & exit is also good - I've got those set as s.cmd and sx.cmd respectively. Also x.cmd for exit, because yes I'm that lazy.

Comment: You could also do "explorer ."

Comment: start actually works for any file type you can double-click on (word documents, xls files, etc) as well as drive mappings (not just the current working directory).

Comment: or if you want an explorer pane on the left side:
    start explorer /e,.

Comment: Note that start can be a bit funny if you have files with spaces in their names. If start's first argument is quoted, it interprets it as a request to change the window title. So instead of running: 

start "My File.txt"

you have to enter:

start "" "My File.txt"

This drove me nuts until someone explained it to me!

Comment: Remarkably just `start` (without the .) opens another identical command window

Answer (score 50):

Remote Desktop Connection

```
mstsc.exe
```

Opens:

[image: Some image demonstrationg the use of mstsc.exe.]

Comment: Love this one, and use it lots! Saves so much more time with WinKey+R, mstsc.

Comment: Even better with the /v: switch. Just Win+R, then "mstsc /v:computer.fabrikam.com"

Comment: Also the /console switch

Comment: renamed to /admin switch these days, and behaves quite differently in 2008+

Comment: don't forget the /span option for creating really big sessions across two monitors.

Comment: Renamed back to /console in Vista SP1 and later, because they shouldn't have changed it in the first place. :)

Comment: While we're at it, I also often use /w: and /h: to manually set width and height. I'm particularly fond of running IIS Manager in 800x800 for some reason.

Comment: /console (or /admin) switch is useful when you only have limited number of connections allowed in the network.

Comment: usually i just type remote at start button for this one

Comment: /f for fullscreen

Comment: I use mstsc /w:2560 /h:1024 /v:"servername" if I want to match my desktop size.

Comment: What does this stand for? I always thought "Microsoft Terminal Service Connection"? At least thats what I say in my head.

Answer (score 45):

A list I use a lot:

- nbtstat - List NetBIOS stats and information
- netstat - List TCP/IP stats and information
- ipconfig - List TCP/IP configuration for a system
- netsh - Network configuration for a system
- sc - manage services
- net - whole slew of commands to manage users and groups, shares, connections, etc.
- ping - makes sure a system is up on the network
- tracert - trace the hops between two hosts. useful to see if there's a break in between and where it is.
- nslookup - Query DNS for information
- dcdiag - check health of the domain controller
- setspn - check SPNs for Kerberos configuration

Comment: sorry, what is the use of "sc"?

Comment: sc allows you to control services, and it allows you to do so remotely. This is different from net start/net stop, which run locally (albeit you can use psexec or something like that to get to a console on a remote system). sc will also query the service, etc. Basically everything you can do from services.msc you can now do from the command-line.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599.aspx

Comment: netsh seems like a really powerful command, but I have not really been able to work with it. What do people really use it for?

Answer (score 43):

Services control panel:

```
services.msc
```

Comment: find myself using this alot

Comment: You can also type this (and the names of other MMC snap-ins) into the Run dialog.

services.msc and compmgmt.msc are my most commonly used entries.

Comment: You can use SC to manager services from the command prompt. Of course the venerable net command can start and stop services.

Answer (score 41):

```
shutdown.exe
```

allow you to shutdown or reboot a machine. You can even reboot a remote machine with

```
shutdown -m \\server -t 0 -r
```

It even comes with a graphical user interface

```
shutdown -i
```

and you can abort a shutdown with

```
shutdown -a
```

Comment: Ouch, I don't think I will be trying this out often unless I do it on a VM ;)

Comment: I use this at the end of my end-of-week script.

Comment: This one's essential for us.  We're an app group and our IT's centrally located out-of-state.  We have local admin access to all of our servers and can reboot at will.  It's not unusual for TS to choke when trying to shutdown and this is the only thing that we can use to kick things back into shape without calling an operator.

Comment: give it a -f as well to force all open apps to close

Answer (score 37):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) is really useful. It mirrors directories.

It is great for backups, restoring, and transferring large amounts of files. It only transfers files which have changed and can resume from where it left off.

It comes standard in Windows Vista and later, but Windows XP users can get it as part of the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit (free) or later.

Comment: Robocopy does so much more than mirror directories. It's freeking amazing! Any command-line tool that requires a word document to explain it rocks in my book.

Comment: hehe.  Well I guess it's a swiss-army-knife of command line copying, but with no GUI nonsense.

Comment: +1; Robocopy, tar, split and gzip form basically all of our backup strategy.

Comment: @RainyRat: What, no 'at' command?

Comment: Is this the `rsync` of Windows?

Comment: Well *I* use it as an rsync equivalent.  But it doesn't do everything rsync does, obviously, like transferring over SSH, the smart delta transferring ability, etc.  What it does do is robustly copy files, and all their attributes and permissions, in a way that it doesn't matter if the operation is interrupted (it can be safely and robustly resumed).  Useful for backups or when you move to a new drive/filesystem.

Answer (score 34):

(Not really a command per-se, but a way to get there.)

For those of you that find yourself going to Start > Run > "cmd" a lot, you can cut down some steps.

Say you want to get your IP address. You would normally go Start > Run > "cmd" [enter]
then...

```
ipconfig [enter]
```

Now instead, go...

Start > Run > "cmd /k ipconfig"

This will run cmd and the command 'ipconfig', and it will keep the window open. So if I want to quickly get my MAC address (physical address), I'd do:

```
 cmd /k ipconfig /all
```

...all from the run menu in one line.

---

All courtesy of [BostonMark](http://lifehacker.com/software/top/contest--win-a-vista-beta-dvd-with-your-best-windows-tip-184775.php#c303993)

Comment: Very cool, I am constantly doing Start>Run>Cmd to run various common commands and didn't know this shortcut.

Comment: Yes, the /k flag is definitely one of the best tips here.

Comment: Here's a better way:
Go to START > All Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt, and right-click.
Select Properties.
Click the 'Short-cut' tab.
Put the cursor in the 'Shortcut Key' field.
Press [ctrl]-[alt]-t, it should say "Ctrl+Alt+T".
Click OK.

Now you can launch cmd.exe from anywhere anytime by hitting ctrl-alt-t.

Comment: Also, using windowskey+r gets you directly to the "Run..." window.

Comment: How is this quicker or fewer keystrokes than opening cmd and typing the command?  Seems to me two more keystrokes than the way you're proposing to replace.

Answer (score 28):

The forgotten art: **DOS String Manipulation!**

```
set mydate=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%
echo %mydate%
```

Output will be `YYYY_MM_DD`.

Copy and paste this into a .bat file and be amazed! This is especially useful for creating backups, or any time/date series of directories and files.

An example:

```
@echo off
:: Yes, this looks bad, but it works, it sets the file veriable mydate to YYYY_MM_DD.
set mydate=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%

echo Backing up DC1:
:: start a new backup session, the /M switch is for the type of bakcup being performed, type ntbackup /? for more info
start /wait ntbackup backup \\DC1\c$ /j "DC1 Backup" /f "C:\BAK\DC1\DC1_%mydate%.bkf" /M incremental
echo DC1 is Done

echo Backing up EXCH:
start /wait ntbackup backup \\EXCH\c$ /j "EXCH Backup" /f "C:\BAK\EXCH\EXCH_%mydate%.bkf" /M incremental
echo EXCH is Done

echo Backing up FS1:
start /wait ntbackup backup \\FS1\c$ /j "FS1 Backup" /f "C:\BAK\FS1\FS1_%mydate%.bkf" /M incremental
echo FS1 is Done

echo Backup was completed %date% %time%
pause
```

Comment: This is dangerous as hell as the system locale display format changes the string that date returns and hence will thrash any script based on character position into an unpredictable mess if it ever changes. Which at least in Europe can easily happen by mistake or on purpose - I've had scheduled batch scripts do horrible things (or nothing) because of exactly this ^^

Comment: Well ... I would hope that people wouldn't copy/paste/pray on production systems ... :-) Good point though.

Answer (score 26):

```
tasklist.exe
```

will list processes on local or a remote machine.

```
tasklist.exe /S server
```

It can display which Services the scvhost.exe processes are hosting with

```
tasklist /SVC
```

You can also do some filtering. This will display the processes on a remote machine that have used more than 15 minutes of CPU time

```
tasklist /S server /FI "CPUTIME gt 00:15:00"
```

Comment: Don't forget it's counterpart `taskkill`

Answer (score 25):

> `control userpasswords2`

Opens the classic User Accounts dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 24):

I find that I use `findstr` a lot to find stuff in logs, error files, etc.

A simple example: in the log file `ex0905.log` we find all lines that have `2009-05-05` in them:

```
findstr "2009-05-05" ex0905.log
```

Comment: findstr /s find recursively

Comment: Put `@findstr %*` into a file named `fs.bat` in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 22):

Programs and Features (Formerly known as "Add or Remove Programs")

```
appwiz.cpl
```

Opens

[image]

Comment: Windows, then "fea" also isolates it well.. (But +1)

Comment: @Farseeker: I ran out of my 80G space as I was taking screenshot.  Coudln't even spare a couple of megs at the time ;)

Comment: You often need to do control appwiz.cpl - especially if you're doing it under runas (as you probably should be!)

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes I have to worry about too few free sessions for a Terminal Server connection to a server.

`quser` displays information about user sessions on a terminal server.

```
quser /SERVER:myserver
```

**Output**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sysmanager01>quser /SERVER:serverx
USERNAME                    SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
usr_hot1                                        1  Disc        none   30.04.2009 17:59
usr_hot                                         2  Disc        none   30.04.2009 18:01
appsuperuser                rdp-tcp#6           3  Conn            .  01.01.1601 02:00
```

Sometimes it's even possible to find pure workaholics like `appsuperuser` :-)

It's easier when pasting the ***quser*** executable from any 32-bit Server to my local System32 folder.

Comment: What version of Windows is "quser" available?

Comment: Try using qwinsta instead, it's included by default in clients like XP as well... rwinsta can nuke the sessions

Answer (score 17):

I use

```
qwinsta
```

to see disconnected remote desktop sessions and

```
logoff
```

to end them.

It works on [Windows 2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_2000), [Windows XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP), [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista), [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) and probably [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) (never tried).

Comment: you can use rwinsta to boot the remote session by id too!

Comment: thats incredible. im impressed.

Answer (score 16):

Computer Management

```
compmgmt.msc
```

Opens
[image]

Answer (score 16):

```
systeminfo
```

Displays a ton of information about the system at hand.  The following are what it outputs on Vista:

- Host Name
- OS Name
- OS Version
- OS Manufacturer
- OS Configuration
- OS Build Type
- Registered Owner
- Registered Organization
- Product ID
- Original Install Date
- System Boot Time
- System Manufacturer
- System Model
- System Type
- Processor(s)
- BIOS Version
- Windows Directory
- System Directory
- Boot Device
- System Locale
- Input Locale
- Time Zone
- Total Physical Memory
- Available  Physical Memory
- Page File
- Max Size
- Page File
- Available
- Page File
- In Use
- Page File Location(s)
- Domain
- Logon Server
- Hotfix(s)
- Network Card(s)

Comment: this is really useful. did not know this one

Answer (score 15):

Very useful one I only found out about recently:

```
winver.exe
```

Gives you a dialog box with the version of Windows the machine is running, complete with Service Pack level and build number.

Comment: Note that I use the hotkey Win+Pause to see most of this information quickly on a box.

Answer (score 14):

There is still no mention of WMIC.exe :)

Find whatever you want from remote machine, local machine... multiple machines.

Nicely filled out HTML page with all data related to OS

```
WMIC OS get /all /format:htable
```

Look at all the options available

```
ALIAS                    - Access to the aliases available on the local system
BASEBOARD                - Base board (also known as a motherboard or system board) management.
BIOS                     - Basic input/output services (BIOS) management.
BOOTCONFIG               - Boot configuration management.
CDROM                    - CD-ROM management.
COMPUTERSYSTEM           - Computer system management.
CPU                      - CPU management.
CSPRODUCT                - Computer system product information from SMBIOS.
DATAFILE                 - DataFile Management.
DCOMAPP                  - DCOM Application management.
DESKTOP                  - User's Desktop management.
DESKTOPMONITOR           - Desktop Monitor management.
DEVICEMEMORYADDRESS      - Device memory addresses management.
DISKDRIVE                - Physical disk drive management.
DISKQUOTA                - Disk space usage for NTFS volumes.
DMACHANNEL               - Direct memory access (DMA) channel management.
ENVIRONMENT              - System environment settings management.
FSDIR                    - Filesystem directory entry management.
GROUP                    - Group account management.
IDECONTROLLER            - IDE Controller management.
IRQ                      - Interrupt request line (IRQ) management.
JOB                      - Provides  access to the jobs scheduled using the schedule service.
LOADORDER                - Management of system services that define execution dependencies.
LOGICALDISK              - Local storage device management.
LOGON                    - LOGON Sessions.
MEMCACHE                 - Cache memory management.
MEMLOGICAL               - System memory management (configuration layout and availability of memory).
MEMPHYSICAL              - Computer system's physical memory management.
NETCLIENT                - Network Client management.
NETLOGIN                 - Network login information (of a particular user) management.
NETPROTOCOL              - Protocols (and their network characteristics) management.
NETUSE                   - Active network connection management.
NIC                      - Network Interface Controller (NIC) management.
NICCONFIG                - Network adapter management.
NTDOMAIN                 - NT Domain management.
NTEVENT                  - Entries in the NT Event Log.
NTEVENTLOG               - NT eventlog file management.
ONBOARDDEVICE            - Management of common adapter devices built into the motherboard (system board).
OS                       - Installed Operating System/s management.
PAGEFILE                 - Virtual memory file swapping management.
PAGEFILESET              - Page file settings management.
PARTITION                - Management of partitioned areas of a physical disk.
PORT                     - I/O port management.
PORTCONNECTOR            - Physical connection ports management.
PRINTER                  - Printer device management.
PRINTERCONFIG            - Printer device configuration management.
PRINTJOB                 - Print job management.
PROCESS                  - Process management.
PRODUCT                  - Installation package task management.
QFE                      - Quick Fix Engineering.
QUOTASETTING             - Setting information for disk quotas on a volume.
RECOVEROS                - Information that will be gathered from memory when the operating system fails.
REGISTRY                 - Computer system registry management.
SCSICONTROLLER           - SCSI Controller management.
SERVER                   - Server information management.
SERVICE                  - Service application management.
SHARE                    - Shared resource management.
SOFTWAREELEMENT          - Management of the  elements of a software product installed on a system.
SOFTWAREFEATURE          - Management of software product subsets of SoftwareElement.
SOUNDDEV                 - Sound Device management.
STARTUP                  - Management of commands that run automatically when users log onto the computer system.
SYSACCOUNT               - System account management.
SYSDRIVER                - Management of the system driver for a base service.
SYSTEMENCLOSURE          - Physical system enclosure management.
SYSTEMSLOT               - Management of physical connection points including ports,  slots and peripherals, and
TAPEDRIVE                - Tape drive management.
TEMPERATURE              - Data management of a temperature sensor (electronic thermometer).
TIMEZONE                 - Time zone data management.
UPS                      - Uninterruptible power supply (UPS) management.
USERACCOUNT              - User account management.
VOLTAGE                  - Voltage sensor (electronic voltmeter) data management.
VOLUMEQUOTASETTING       - Associates the disk quota setting with a specific disk volume.
WMISET                   - WMI service operational parameters management.
```

and many, many more.

Comment: @KAPes: "/format:htable" is awesome...

Answer (score 13):

Chaining commands, in particular `net stop` and `start` to restart any service:

```
net stop w3svc && net start w3svc
```

(It is a silly example as `iisreset` will do that, but anyway ;)

Comment: Just pointing out this is actually conditional execution, unlike a single '&'. http://www.ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html

Comment: True, it will only start if it the stop succeeded... or I guess that's the spirit anyway - not sure the net stop would actually return a non-success if it timed out..  *testing*

Comment: Well as it does both even if one tries to stop a non-existing service, in this case it doesn't seem to matter - but the difference is of course great. They should add that "promote comment to answer" feature and I'd promote yours ^^

Comment: This will ensure a metabase configuration change is saved, however. IISRESET does not.

Answer (score 13):

```
color 02
```

This, my friends, is the only command you'll ever need. The rest is nonessential.

Comment: Oops, I accidentally entered color 23...

Comment: entering 'color' by itself takes you back to default

Comment: Too bad it doesn't stick across CMD sessions...

Answer (score 12):

```
explorer .
```

Open explorer with the current folder selected.

```
explorer /e, .
```

Open explorer, with folder tree, with current folder selected.

Comment: This is also the way to make a shortcut that opens explorer for a specific directory, like "explorer /e,c:\myhomeisinrootthxu

Comment: Already integrated higher up the vote count...

Answer (score 12):

To change the title of the CMD window you have open, simply use:

`title [your new title]`

I've got a lot of CMD windows and other programs open at work. This command, combined with Taskbar Shuffle (allows you to drag taskbar items into new orders) has saved me from insanity.

Answer (score 11):

[Windows 7 Run Commands](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5966-run-commands-windows-7-a.html)

I find it better to know where to find them until I have used them often enough to actually remember them.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I was looking for a list like those.  My initial goal was to be able to browse through answers and find whatever a user might think will need by skimming through screenshots.  But I guess I could do that myself ;)

Answer (score 10):

On Windows XP at least (I haven't tried on Windows Vista and Windows 7):

```
appwiz.cpl @,2
```

It takes you straight to the Add/Remove Windows Components pane.

Another way to add or remove components in an automated fashion is to use

```
sysocmgr.exe
```

in unattended mode with a .inf file that lists the components you'd like to install. For example,

```
[NetOptionalComponents] 
SNMP = 1 

[SNMP] 
Contact_Name = IT Dept. 
Location = Office
Service = Physical, Applications, End-to-End 
Community_Name = Mormon 
Traps = server1, server2 
Send_Authentication = Yes 
Accept_CommunityName = Public:Read_Only 
Any_Host = No 
Limit_Host = server1, server2
```

(Credit due to thesystemadministrator.com for .inf file.)

It's a clunky tool (hey, it's MS), but it's invaluable for getting your components sorted out post-install.

Comment: "appwiz.cpl @,2" works but renamed to "Turn Windows Features On and Off"

Answer (score 10):

To restart IIS

```
iisreset
```

Comment: This can also be used to restart IIS on a remote server:
iisreset remoteservername

Comment: I don't use iisreset any longer. It may not save metabase config issue. I use net stop iisadmin /y && net start w3svc instead. Here's why: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/286196

Comment: @K. Brian Kelley, pretty sure the `/noforce` command will prevent the forcing and therefore keep you safe. IIS 7 is probably immune to it anyway since it no longer 'technically' uses the metabase.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't see taskkill on the list yet.

> TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P
>   [password]]]]
>            { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/F] [/T]
>
> Parameter List:
>       /S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.
>
> ```
> /U    [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which
>                        the command should execute.
>
> /P    [password]       Specifies the password for the given
>                        user context. Prompts for input if omitted.
>
> /F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate
>                        process(es).
>
> /FI   filter           Displays a set of tasks that match a
>                        given criteria specified by the filter.
>
> /PID  process id       Specifies the PID of the process that
>                        has to be terminated.
>
> /IM   image name       Specifies the image name of the process
>                        that has to be terminated. Wildcard '*'
>                        can be used to specify all image names.
>
> /T                     Tree kill: terminates the specified process
>                        and any child processes which were started by
> ```
>
> it.

Works great in conjunction with tasklist

Answer (score 10):

You can hit F7 in The Windows Command Line for a history of commands that you can choose with your keyboard.

Also...I love this one - you can copy a file path by just dragging a file into the command line.

Answer (score 9):

Device Manager

```
devmgmt.msc
```

Opens

[image]

Comment: If you set the environment variable devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices to 1 before launching device manager, then when you show hidden devices it will show all the completely inactive devices (e.g. have been removed) as well.

Answer (score 8):

EventViewer

```
eventvwr.msc
```

Opens
[image]

Comment: You can just use "eventvwr" and save a few characters.

Answer (score 8):

Registry Editor

```
regedit
```

Answer (score 8):

**Network Connections (Windows Vista/Windows XP)**

The command

```
ncpa.cpl
```

opens

[image]

Comment: ... and so falls a great Vista frustration. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**dsquery * and dsmod**

Pipe your `dsquery` results into `dsmod` and do mass changes to [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory).

```
Description:  Finds any objects in the directory according to criteria.

Syntax:     dsquery * [{<StartNode> | forestroot | domainroot}]
            [-scope {subtree | onelevel | base}] [-filter <LDAPFilter>]
            [-attr {<AttrList> | *}] [-attrsonly] [-l]
            [{-s <Server> | -d <Domain>}] [-u <UserName>]
            [-p {<Password> | *}] [-q] [-r] [-gc]
            [{-uc | -uco | -uci}]

Parameters:
Value                       Description
{<StartNode> | forestroot | domainroot}
                            The node where the search will start:
                            forest root, domain root, or a node
                            whose DN is <StartNode>.
                            Can be "forestroot", "domainroot" or an object
                            DN.
                            If "forestroot" is specified, the search is done
                            via the global catalog. Default: domainroot.
-scope {subtree | onelevel | base}
                            Specifies the scope of the search:
                            subtree rooted at start node (subtree);
                            immediate children of start node only (onelevel);
                            the base object represented by start node (base).
                            Note that subtree and domain scope
                            are essentially the same for any start node
                            unless the start node represents a domain root.
                            If forestroot is specified as <StartNode>,
                            subtree is the only valid scope.
                            Default: subtree.
-filter <LDAPFilter>        Specifies that the search use the explicit
                            LDAP search filter <LDAPFilter> specified in the
                            LDAP search filter format for searching.
                            Default:(objectCategory=*).The search filter
                            string must be enclosed in double quotes.
-attr {<AttrList> | *}      If <AttrList>, specifies a space-separated list
                            of LDAP display names to be returned for
                            each entry in the result set.
                            If *, specifies all attributes present on
                            the objects in the result set.
                            Default: distinguishedName.
-attrsonly                  Shows only the attribute types present on
                            the entries in the result set but not
                            their values.
                            Default: shows both attribute type and value.
-l                          Shows the entries in the search result set
                            in a list format. Default: table format.
{-s <Server> | -d <Domain>}
                            -s <Server> connects to the domain controller
                            (DC) with name <Server>.
                            -d <Domain> connects to a DC in domain <Domain>.
                            Default: a DC in the logon domain.
-u <UserName>               Connect as <UserName>. Default: the logged in
                            user. User name can be: user name,
                            domain\user name, or user principal name (UPN).
-p <Password>               Password for the user <UserName>. If * then you
                            are prompted for a password.
-q                          Quiet mode: suppress all output to standard
                            output.
-r                          Recurse or follow referrals during search.
                            Default: do not chase referrals during search.
-gc                         Search in the Active Directory global catalog.
-limit <NumObjects>         Specifies the number of objects matching the
                            given criteria to be returned, where <NumObjects>
                            is the number of objects to be returned.
                            If the value of <NumObjects> is 0, all matching
                            objects are returned. If this parameter is not
                            specified, by default the first 100 results are
                            displayed.
{-uc | -uco | -uci}         -uc Specifies that input from or output to pipe
                            is formatted in Unicode.
                            -uco Specifies that output to pipe or file is
                            formatted in Unicode.
                            -uci Specifies that input from pipe or file is
                            formatted in Unicode.

Remarks:
The dsquery commands help you find objects in the directory that match
a specified search criterion: the input to dsquery is a search criteria
and the output is a list of objects matching the search. To get the
properties of a specific object, use the dsget commands (dsget /?).

A user-entered value containing spaces or semicolons must be enclosed in
quotes (""). Multiple user-entered values must be separated using commas
(for example, a list of attribute types).


Examples:
To find all users in the current domain only whose SAM account name begins
with the string "jon" and display their SAM account name,
User Principal Name (UPN) and department in table format:

dsquery * domainroot
-filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=jon*))"
-attr sAMAccountName userPrincipalName department

To read the sAMAccountName, userPrincipalName and department attributes of
the object whose DN is ou=Test,dc=microsoft,dc=com:

Dsquery * ou=Test,dc=microsoft,dc=com -scope base
-attr sAMAccountName userPrincipalName department

To read all attributes of the object whose DN is ou=Test,dc=microsoft,dc=com:

Dsquery * ou=Test,dc=microsoft,dc=com -scope base -attr *

See also:
dsquery computer /? - help for finding computers in the directory.
dsquery contact /? - help for finding contacts in the directory.
dsquery subnet /? - help for finding subnets in the directory.
dsquery group /? - help for finding groups in the directory.
dsquery ou /? - help for finding organizational units in the directory.
dsquery site /? - help for finding sites in the directory.
dsquery server /? - help for finding servers in the directory.
dsquery user /? - help for finding users in the directory.
dsquery quota /? - help for finding quotas in the directory.
dsquery partition /? - help for finding partitions in the directory.
dsquery * /? - help for finding any object in the directory by using
a generic LDAP query.

Directory Service command-line tools help:
dsadd /? - help for adding objects.
dsget /? - help for displaying objects.
dsmod /? - help for modifying objects.
dsmove /? - help for moving objects.
dsquery /? - help for finding objects matching search criteria.
dsrm /? - help for deleting objects.
dsquery failed:The parameter is incorrect.
type dsquery /? for help.
```

Answer (score 8):

**fsutil**

From Microsoft Technet "Performs tasks that are related to file allocation table (FAT) and NTFS file systems, such as managing reparse points, managing sparse files, or dismounting a volume."

One of its most helpful options is to disable the creation of legacy 8.3 filenames.  This is particularly helpful on servers that have very large numbers of files in a directory with long filenames.

To disable legacy 8.3 filenames on XP or Server 2003:

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1
```

On Windows 7 (and possibly Vista and Server 2008) you'd use:

```
fsutil 8dot3name set 1
```

For more information see: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753059.aspx

Comment: I can confirm "fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1" is the correct command on Server 2008

Comment: fsutil can also be used to create hardlinks (and other useful but relatively hidden FS features/capabilities)

Answer (score 8):

[ipconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig)

> USAGE:
>
> ```
> ipconfig [/? | /all | /renew [adapter] | /release [adapter] |
>
>           /flushdns | /displaydns | /registerdns |
>
>           /showclassid adapter |
>
>           /setclassid adapter [classid] ]
> ```
>
> where
>
> ```
> adapter         Connection name 
>
>                (wildcard characters * and ? allowed, see
> ```
>
> examples)
>
> ```
> Options:
>
>    /?           Display this help message
>
>    /all         Display full configuration information.
>
>    /release     Release the IP address for the specified adapter.
>
>    /renew       Renew the IP address for the specified adapter.
>
>    /flushdns    Purges the DNS Resolver cache.
>
>    /registerdns Refreshes all DHCP leases and re-registers DNS names
>
>    /displaydns  Display the contents of the DNS Resolver Cache.
>
>    /showclassid Displays all the dhcp class IDs allowed for adapter.
>
>    /setclassid  Modifies the dhcp class id.
> ```
>
> The default is to display only the IP
>   address, subnet mask and
>
> default gateway for each adapter bound
>   to TCP/IP.
>
> For Release and Renew, if no adapter
>   name is specified, then the IP address
>
> leases for all adapters bound to
>   TCP/IP will be released or renewed.
>
> For Setclassid, if no ClassId is
>   specified, then the ClassId is
>   removed.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> > ipconfig                   ... Show information.
>
> > ipconfig /all              ... Show detailed information
>
> > ipconfig /renew            ... renew all adapters
>
> > ipconfig /renew EL*        ... renew any connection that has its 
>
>                                  name starting with EL
>
> > ipconfig /release *Con*    ... release all matching connections,
>
>                                  eg. "Local Area Connection 1" or
>
>                                      "Local Area Connection 2"
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Run something as a different user (good for troubleshooting w/o having people to log off)

```
runas /U:*domainname*\*username* "*someapplication*"
```

for example, if you want to open an explorer window with your credentials

```
runas /U:example.com\mylogin "explorer /separate"
```

for management console snapins (services in this example) you need to use mmc followed by the normal command to open that snap-in

```
runas /U:example.com\mylogin "mmc services.msc"
```

For situations where you need to run an application as a domain user from a non-domain-joined PC (eg SQL Server Management Studio)

```
runas /netonly /U:domain\username application.exe
```

Answer (score 8):

```
netsh firewall set opmode disable
```

turns off the Windows firewall.

```
taskkill.exe /f /fi "status eq Not Responding"
```

kills all not responding programs.

Answer (score 8):

I just recently found out about **forfiles**

> FORFILES [/P pathname] [/M searchmask]
>   [/S] [/C command] [/D [+ | -]
>   {MM/dd/yyyy | dd}]
>
> Description:
>       Selects a file (or set of files) and executes a
>       command on that file. This is helpful for batch jobs.

I use this to delete old backups with this line, this basically deletes files that are older than 6 days:

```
Forfiles /p " C:\Backups\SQL " /d -6 /c "CMD /C del @FILE"
```

Comment: What Windows version do you have? It doesn't work on my Windows XP Pro SP3. Maybe I need to modify some Environment variable?

Answer (score 6):

**Windows Update Service**

```
wuauclt.exe 

/demoui
/a /ResetAuthorization
/r /ReportNow
/detectnow
```

This single command has a lot of mythology surrounding it. It reports no errors, has no help dialog, and the only real output is run for `/demoui`. But it does work, I think.

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720477.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

The **clip** command on Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 is very useful: it puts anything passed in on standard input on the clipboard.

Examples:

Copy current directory to clipboard:

```
dir | clip
```

List C files containing a particular string:

```
findstr /i /s /m /c:"someFunction" *.c | clip
```

Answer (score 6):

I find that often I need to create large files for testing.

`fsutil file createnew C:\1_gb-ish_file.txt 1000000000`

Comment: I cant believe I didnt know this.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

```
mstsc  # starts the Remote Desktop window.
mstsc -v 192.168.0.1  # to remotely connect to a given IP.
```

Comment: Learned about this one about a year ago. Use it all the time now and can't live without it!

Answer (score 6):

To get the current date / time for use in a batch file:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%w in (`echo %DATE%`) do set YMD=%%z%%x%%y
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=:." %%x in (`echo %TIME%`) do set HMS=%%x%%y%%z
set NOW=%YMD%_%HMS%
echo %NOW%
```

Answer (score 5):

`rasdial`

> ```
> USAGE:
>     rasdial entryname [username [password|*]] [/DOMAIN:domain]
>             [/PHONE:phonenumber] [/CALLBACK:callbacknumber]
>             [/PHONEBOOK:phonebookfile]
>             [/PREFIXSUFFIX]
>
>     rasdial [entryname] /DISCONNECT
>
>     rasdial
>
>     For Online Privacy Information please refer to
>     'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=34493'
> ```

connects to a VPN or a dialup network from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Quite possibly the most powerful command yet:

```
cmd.exe
```

Favorite option:

/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Answer (score 5):

subst.exe - associates a path with a drive letter, including local drives.  Usage example (add then remove):

```
subst M: C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Music\
subst M: /D
```

(note: is not persistent and needs to be run on every logon)

Comment: Be aware that this can overlap with mapped network drives or removable drives - sometimes the contents of the network/removable drive appears in Explorer under the SUBST drive letter or vice versa!

Answer (score 5):

Lately I have had to use:  `net use \\servername /d`

It kills permissions to specified resources.

Another use for `net use` is to re-mount a local drive as administrator, so that you don't need to log out (on WinXP, switch user was disabled on domains).

`net use \\localShare /user:admin`

Answer (score 5):

Disk management from the command line:

```
diskpart
```

See *[A Description of the Diskpart Command-Line Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415)* for more information.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a bit of an old question here, but I looked through the five pages of answers, and I did not see the following:

```
pushd, popd
```

Usage:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\src> pushd C:\Users\MyUser\Documents
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents> cd Backup
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Backup> copy ..\*.* .
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Backup> popd
C:\Users\MyUser\src> rem Continue working in src directory.
```

Useful when working in long directories. I want to get back **where i was**.

Answer (score 4):

Forfiles:

```
forfiles
```

This is great for running a given command on any file that matches a list of criteria.

For example, the following will delete all files with a last modified date earlier than seven days ago:

```
forfiles -p . /D -7 /M *.* /S -c "cmd /C del @File /Q"
```

Answer (score 4):

What about `rundll32.exe`?
It allows running functions from within any 32 bit DLL.
You can do almost everything with this command - and script your OS to your heart's content.
The syntax is:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE <dllname>,<entrypoint> <optional arguments>
```

E.G.:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,Control_RunDLL HotPlug.dll
```

Will bring up the "USB Disconnect" dialog (equivalent to right-clicking the "Safely Remove Hardware option in the system tray).

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /?
```

Will give you dozens of options to control your printer from the command line.
And there are millions more...

Answer (score 4):

### netsh

`netsh` can do many useful things, i.e: (no pun intended ;-)
Import proxy settings from Internet Options to command line tools:

```
netsh
netsh>winhttp
netsh winhttp>import proxy source=ie
```

Display current proxy settings:

```
netsh winhttp>show proxy
```

### net config server

Hide computer from Browser list:

```
net config server /hidden:yes
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]#####Mouse Properties
    control mouse

-- or --

```
main.cpl
```

Opens

Answer (score 3):

Network and Sharing Center

```
control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter
```

**Reference**: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733147.aspx#BKMK_Anchor3

Opens
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Local Security Settings

```
secpol.msc
```

Comment: hhmmm.............

Answer (score 3):

To free up some disk space:

```
format c:
```

No, really, here's Disk Cleanup:

```
cleanmgr.exe
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The ever-so-appropriately named lusrmgr.msc - Local Users and Groups Administrator

Comment: I've typed it hundreds of times but never got the pun until just now. Hilarious.

Answer (score 3):

To open the ***Windows Event Log*** (Event Viewer).

```
Eventvwr
```

[image]

Comment: And I always thought I had to do eventvwr.msc...thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you suspect something's wrong with protected system files, you can use this tool.

```
sfc /scannow
```

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool

```
mrt
```

Answer (score 3):

SC - Manage anything you want to do with services.

```
DESCRIPTION:
        SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
        NT Service Controller and services. USAGE:
        sc <server> [command] [service name] <option1> <option2>...
```

Answer (score 3):

The **set** command with filtering to display contents of environment variables. Instead of typing

```
C:\Users\Erlend>echo %computername%
ASUS-G1S
```

you can type

```
C:\Users\Erlend>set comp
COMPUTERNAME=ASUS-G1S
```

to get the same effect. Using **set** alone shows you all environment variables.

Comment: Just learned the SET alone command to list environment variables thats a great one.

Answer (score 3):

One of my favourites is `rsop.msc`, 'Resultant Set of Policy'.

RSoP shows the combined effect of all group policies active on the current system/login. So on a client machine if you're unsure about which particular policy settings are/aren't applied, simply check it out in RSoP!

Answer (score 3):

The two I use the most are:

`PathPing` - Traces the route and pings the site at the same time (ie: pathping www.zdnet.com)

and an easy way to lock your workstation/server:

```
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Comment: Any easy way to lock a workstation is windows+L. No need for the command.

Comment: @railmeat:  Yes, I use that too.  But if you are remotely on the box, it's a little difficult to hit it sometimes...

Answer (score 3):

start:

```
start .                (opens explorer to the pwd)

start c:\              (opens explorer to the root of C:)

start document.doc     (open the document - just like double-clicking on it)

start wordpad file.txt (open wordpad for the file, creating if necessary)

start calc             (launch the calculator app)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cipher /w:C:\
```

> /W        Removes data from available unused disk space on the entire volume. If this option is chosen, all other options are ignored. The directory specified can be anywhere in a local volume. If it is a mount point or points to a directory in another volume, the data on that volume will be removed.

support.microsoft.com/kb/814599

Answer (score 3):

Monitor network connections in the background, command-line while you work. (AKA - The `revolving netstat'):

```
> netstat -a 1
```

Stop services via command-line:

```
> net stop [servicename]
```

Fire up a Terminal Services session to a remote computer, via command-line:

```
> mstsc /v:[servername]
```

They kept around the "more" command, which was nice. Check out what's going on with the latest updates that have been installed, via WSUS:

```
> more /c c:\windows\windowsupdate.log
```

Problems with resolving via netBIOS? (Remember that buggy-ole-protocol?) Or issues with domain trusts? This set of commands has always served well on old domain controllers. (Also demonstrates how to link commands, (the double-ampersand means, `only continue if the last command completed successfully')

```
> nbtstat -R && nbtstat -r & nbtstat -c
```

Answer (score 3):

[cacls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls) (or the more up-to-date [icalcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacls)):

> cacls (Change Access Control Lists) is a command line utility for Microsoft Windows to change Access Control List (ACL) permissions on a directory, its subcontents, or files. An access control list is a list of permissions for a securable object, such as a file or directory, that controls who can access it.

[alt text http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/i/tr/cms/contentPics/r00220020626van01_02.gif](http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/i/tr/cms/contentPics/r00220020626van01_02.gif)

It is a real life-saver on a file-server when specific file(s) and/or directory(s) permissions have to be modified.

Answer (score 3):

Useful for batch/cmd processing:

```
cd %0\..
```

changes the path including the drive to the directory where the batch/cmd files is located.

For example, when you have your bat/cmd in `z:\test`, and you open up a shortcut to the bat/cmd from your desktop, with the command inside your bat/cmd you can change the path to z:\test and go on from there.

Edit: the command above only changes the path, not the drive! My fault... I tested it only on the same drive. The correct command for also changing the drive would be

```
cd /d %0\..
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows key + r
cmd

This opens the command-line window without the mouse. It is the quickest way I've found to get it up. Combine with the `cmd \k *command*` mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

[`chkdsk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chkdsk) (or `checkdisk`) is a command that checks the disk surface for physical errors or bad sectors. It can also fix logical file system errors.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this fits in here - exporting the results of a command to file. For example, running a ping:

```
ping localhost
```

Can be exported to a log file:

```
ping localhost > C:\ping.log
```

Anything that would otherwise appear within the console screen, will be written to the file. Very useful for creating logs of running scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 3):

I saw FINDSTR listed above but nobody mentioned FIND.  This command is incredibly useful to search the list returned from another command.
Example:
netstat -an | find ":6667"

This command will find any IRC traffic on your computer.  Substitute another port or an IP address to narrow down the returned results accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I seem to regularly use "sc stop wuauserv", which turns off the [Windows Update](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Update) service. Primarly to make it stop nagging me to restart every few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

The **arp** command gives you the IP address and Ethernet address for hosts your machine knows of on the network. Very useful to debug hairy network troubles... I usually use

```
arp -a
```

Answer (score 3):

I find that MS's [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals) are really useful. So I often keep the folder updated by running this robocopy [command](http://gist.github.com/99151):

```
robocopy "\\live.sysinternals.com\Tools" "C:\utils\sysinternals" /LEV:0 /Z /XO /IT /R:10 /W:10
```

The three I use the most are:

- `autoruns.exe` manage processes that start automatically
- `procexp.exe` a heavy duty process explorer, great for finding file locks
- `contig.exe` defragment a single file (useful for virtual machines)

Answer (score 3):

```
mode
```

It allows you to resize your cmd.exe window.

The cmd.exe window normally has 300 lines and 80 columns, which can be quite small sometimes.

You can double the height and width of the command window with

```
mode con cols=160 lines=600
```

To see your current settings use

```
mode con /status
```

Answer (score 3):

When I was testing my WSUS server I found these useful:

```
gpresult > gp.txt (gives the policies aplied)

gpupdate /force (will force an group policy update on the machine)

wuauclt /detectnow (to force the Windows update agent to search for updates)
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem Steps Recorder - A beautiful new feature in Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2.

```
PSR.EXE
```

Answer (score 2):

Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager

```
InetMgr.exe - IIS 7
InetMgr6.exe - IIS 6
```

- IIS 7 
  [image]
- IIS 6 
  [image]

Comment: God´s home is on Vista?

Comment: @Decio: Beh, it's all capitalized ;)

Answer (score 2):

ODBC Data Source Administrator

```
odbcad32.exe
```

Opens
[image]

Comment: Is it wrong to be happy not to have seen this screen in years?

Comment: @Philoushka I had to see that screen everyday while setting up some 3rd party Mail application that interacts with Accounting system...

Answer (score 2):

To manage the entire IIS7 from the standard command-line (no PowerShell needed ;)

```
appcmd.exe
```

Comment: For some reason, I am not able to run that command. What version of Windows does that command work under?

Comment: It might not be in the path, which would be %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe I think. Version of Windows is anything with IIS7 installed.

Answer (score 2):

`fsmgmt.msc` to access File Shares.

Comment: +1 I have always went through Computer Management screen for this.

Answer (score 2):

**System Properties**

The command

```
sysdm.cpl
```

opens

[image]

Comment: also available through [windowsbutton]+[break].

Answer (score 2):

Remote Assistance

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\rcimlby.exe -LaunchRA
```

This is very handy to create as a shortcut on a users desktop.  It goes straight to the "Invite someone to help you" page in the help centre.  (Tested on XP/Pro Home).

Answer (score 2):

The Advanced Tab of the System Properties dialog.

```
control sysdm.cpl,@0,3
```

I use this regularly to get to Page file settings, Performance, Environment Variables and User Profiles.

Syntax:

@0  =  the function within sysdm.cpl to display (In this case System Properties)

3   =  the tab number to activate (in this case Advanced)

For anyone interested, Victor Laurie provides more info on [this syntax](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/control.htm).

Answer (score 2):

**calc** to open Calculator.

Comment: ??????..........

Comment: set path=c:\sierra\ll4 *ll4* to open up Leisure Suit Larry

Answer (score 2):

```
net statistics workstation
```

or

```
net statistics server
```

One way of finding out how long the box has been up for.

*Note*: The times that these commands report are how long the *Workstation* and *Server* services have been running for. These are normally started with the rest of the OS, but I've seen secure builds that disable *Workstation*.

Answer (score 2):

`cls` clears the command line screen.

It is very useful when you want to run a new command and clear the current screen.

Answer (score 2):

```
reg.exe
```

[manipulates the Windows Registry](http://commandwindows.com/reg.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Windows, [Scheduled Tasks](http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm), and for command-line goodness, the schtasks or at commands.

[schtasks](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/AdminTips/Utilities/XPschtaskscommandlineutilityreplacesAT.exe.html)

```
Parameter List:
    /Create  : Creates a new scheduled task.
    /Delete  : Deletes the scheduled task(s).
    /Query  : Displays all scheduled tasks. 
    /Change  : Changes the properties of scheduled task. 
    /Run  : Runs the scheduled task immediately. 
    /End  : Stops the currently running scheduled task. 
    /?              Displays this help/usage.
```

[at](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)

```
\\computername: Specify a remote computer (default local machine.
time: Specify the time when the task is to run.
/interactive: Allow the task to interact with the desktop of the user who is logged on at the time the task runs.
/every:date,...: Schedule the task to run on the specified day or days of the week or month.
/next:date,...: Schedule the task to run on the next occurrence of the day (for example, next Monday).
command: Specify the command, the program (.exe or .com file), or the batch program (.bat or .cmd file) that you want to run.
id: Specify the identification number that is assigned to a scheduled task.
/delete: Cancel a scheduled task. If you omit the id parameter, all scheduled tasks on the computer are canceled.
/yes: Force a yes answer to all queries from the system when you cancel scheduled tasks.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on one of the more professional Windows distributions (XP Professional, Vista Business, Vista Ultimate), use

```
gpedit.msc
```

to do Group Policy editing.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
powercfg.cpl
```

launches the power management control panel applet.

Comment: This looks awefully useful on my laptpo!

Answer (score 2):

DIRCMD is an environmental variable that the DIR command reads its switches from.

Order directory listing by sub-directories, file extension, and name, 
including hidden and system files:

```
set DIRCMD=/ogen/a

dir
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `pstools` installed in the root of drive C;

```
c:\pstools\psexec \\\\computername -u username -p password cmd
```

opens the command prompt on a remote machine. From there you can do whatever you want.

Comment: to get to backslashes you need to escape each of the backslashes, thus you'll need to enter 4 :)

Comment: I have a /bin folder in my home dir, and I configure my profile to include h:/bin in my path. I drop pstools, gnu32utils, wrktools, etc. into here. If you have roaming profiles, you have all your utils available in the path across the entire network.

Answer (score 2):

Run dxdiag, a DirectX diagnostic tool. Apart from giving DirectX components installed on your system it also gives a system information summary. All information can be exported as a text file.

CIPHER: this is a good one to permanently delete files off the computer. Once a file is deleted, it is only marked as deleted and it won't truly be delted off the hard drive until it's overwritten with the information or you can run cipher and the location of where the file used to be to truly delete it from the hard drive.

Usage:

```
cipher /w:"drive letter":"folder name"
```

Example:

```
 cipher /w:C: (to do all the C: drive.)
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the FOR command to be essential, usually parsing a text file of server names or user accounts. Sure, powershell or vbscript is more versatile, but sometimes the command prompt is what you have.

```
FOR /f %i in (servername.txt) do psexec \\%i netsh int ip show dns
```

(with pstools) runs netsh on multiple servers and outputs their dns settings.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3* skip=8 usebackq" %i in (`net group /domain "Domain Admins"`) do net user /domain %i && net user /domain %j && net user /domain %k
```

Dumps out each Domain Admin in WinNT "net user" style -- doing a dsquery command would be better. Add ">>filename.txt" to each part to save in a file. The >>file format appends. You get an error on the last line from the "net group".

Full command details are in "FOR /?" including string substitution, doing sequences (FOR /L %i IN (start,step,end) gives a loop where %i can be a number) and compound results.

Answer (score 2):

Restart an IIS app pool from the command line:

```
cscript c:\WINDOWS\system32\iisapp.vbs /a SuperDuperAppPool /r
```

Where 'SuperDuperAppPool' is your app pool name

Answer (score 2):

There have been a couple of mentions of WMIC, but there's a lot of power there that isn't being highlighted. Granted, much of this can be done easier now with PowerShell, but if you don't know PowerShell or aren't able to use it for whatever reason, then it's WMIC to the rescue!

You are able to use many of the WQL keywords. For some reason a nice well-documented syntax on how to use these on the command line in conjunction with WMIC is not found anywhere.

### Some examples:

---

#### List the QFE (Quick Fix Engineering) hotfixes installed on a system

// See them all
`wmic qfe | more`

// List the HotFixID, InstalledBy and InstalledOn properties of the ones that begin with "KB9"
`wmic qfe where "HotfixID like '%KB9%'" get HotFixID,InstalledBy,InstalledOn`

// Useful if you're just trying to find out if a particular KB is installed, and you don't care about the properties
`wmic qfe | find "981793"`

// Or, if you need the properties just for the one
`wmic qfe where "HotFixID = 'KB981793'"`

### Display, start and stop services! Very useful when you have a group of related services that you need to stop/start.

// Display McAfee services
`wmic service where "DisplayName like '%McAfee%'"`

// Stop all McAfee services
`wmic service where "DisplayName like '%McAfee%'" call StopService`

### Context-sensitive Help

---

#### See what properties are available with a particular alias:

```
wmic service get /?
```

#### See what methods are available with a particular alias:

```
wmic service call /?
```

#### See which classes the aliases map to:

```
wmic alias list brief
```

### Run a query or command against multiple computers:

---

// Get a list of all the patches on hostname1 and hostname2 and save it as a .csv file for easy import into Excel
`wmic /node:hostname1,hostname2 get /format:csv > Patches.csv`

// You can also list all your systems (one per line) in a text file and run it against all of them:
`wmic /node:@MyServers.txt get /format:csv > Patches.csv`

Answer (score 2):

"| more" is an essential sub-command.  It pauses at each screen, making large amounts of text easier to read.

Examples:

```
dir | more
help | more
type filename.txt | more
```

It saves from scrolling back up to find what you want, and losing your place.

Comment: `more` is already listed in the "question", but it's useful to have it described. However, it's unnecessary for `dir` because it has `/p`. Also, it's unnecessary to pipe `type` into `more`, just do `more filename.txt` (congratulations, you receive the Windows/DOS equivalent of the Useless Use of cat Award).

Comment: Yes, I checked before posting and noticed that more was mentioned, but it didn't summarize how.  While there are alternative ways to pause the screen, 'more' is consistent across all outputs ... and works with other OSes too (including non-Windows).  To me, it's an essential subtool to add to any arsenal of command line syntax lists.

Answer (score 2):

sqlwb 
Starts Microsof SQL Server Management Studio. Handy when you can't find it listed in the start menu, but you know it's installed on that server.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Amazing Shutdown timer:

```
shutdown -s -t 7200 -c "shutting down in 120 mins, please type 'shutdown -a' in a command prompt to cancel" -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Disk Management

```
diskmgmt.msc
```

Opens
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard Properties

```
control keyboard
```

Opens
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Regional and Language Options

```
intl.cpl
```

Opens
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Internet Properties

```
inetcpl.cpl
```

Opens
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Task Manager | taskmgr.exe

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Esc uses fewer keys to open Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

```
desk.cpl
```

opens the display properties. (Sorry, no image)

Comment: @Yuval: Don't worry. When I get enough rep to be able to edit wiki, I will add a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Notepad or something similar

```
notepad
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sound**

The command

```
mmsys.cpl
```

opens

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Date and Time**

The command

```
timedate.cpl
```

opens

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Windows Security Center**

```
wscui.cpl
```

opens

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best way to avoid clicks is to stay on the command line. A directory in your path with the GNU tools and the sysinternals tools will go a long way to making your life simpler. Nothing that a good grep can't fix. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My favorites:

```
ipconfig
tracert
ping
telnet
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dsa.msc
```

is a nice quick way to open up Active Directory Users and Computers.

Answer (score 1):

```
firewall.cpl
```

Opens the Windows Firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

System Configuration

```
msconfig
```

It is very useful to see what runs at startup

Answer (score 1):

[tracert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491018.aspx)

> Usage: tracert [-d] [-h maximum_hops]
>   [-j host-list] [-w timeout]
>   target_name
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> -d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
>
> -h maximum_hops    Maximum number of hops to search for target.
>
> -j host-list       Loose source route along host-list.
>
> -w timeout         Wait timeout milliseconds for each reply.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To quickly open the Exchange 2007 Management Shell:

```
exshell.psc1
```

Active Directory Sites and Services:

```
dssite.msc
```

Basically, anything in the start menu I try to grab the properties of the shortcuts and find out what they actually call.

Oh, and the "elevated" command-prompt in Vista:

Start -> from the Search box "cmd" + Ctrl+Shift+Enter

:)

Answer (score 1):

The items in the following list might be duplicates, but I just want to add it just in case (this is from a buddy's list). This might be more useful to an office worker than to a system administrator though:

1. devmgmt.msc = Device Manager
2. msinfo32 = System Information
3. cleanmgr = Disk Cleanup
4. ntbackup = Backup or Restore Wizard (Windows Backup Utility)
5. mmc = Microsoft Management Console
6. excel = Microsoft Excel (If Installed)
7. msaccess = Microsoft Access (If Installed)
8. powerpnt = Microsoft PowerPoint (If Installed)
9. winword = Microsoft Word (If Installed)
10. frontpg = Microsoft FrontPage (If Installed)
11. notepad = Notepad
12. wordpad = WordPad
13. calc = Calculator
14. msmsgs = Windows Messenger
15. mspaint = Microsoft Paint
16. wmplayer = Windows Media Player
17. rstrui = System Restore
18. netscp6 = Netscape 6.x
19. netscp = Netscape 7.x
20. netscape = Netscape 4.x
21. waol = America Online
22. control = Opens the Control Panel
23. control printers = Opens the Printers Dialog

Answer (score 1):

`pathping` - a [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) that collects detailed packet loss statistics.

Answer (score 1):

To allow user to log on without pressing ctrl-alt-delete, or log on without entering a password:

```
control userpasswords2
```

Comment: @Andomar: Sorry it has already been posted on http://serverfault.com/questions/3780/common-commandline-commands-on-windows/3891#3891

Answer (score 1):

Behold:

```
command.com
```

Very often would I see the system being plagued by trojans/worms that attempt to lock down every way of getting through to system internals like regedit, mmc, cmd.exe, etc. Then you have no choice, but to boot from a live CD. But, obviously, with command.com at your disposal you can do anything you want, and I've yet to see THAT made unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago I started using sync.exe (for file cache flushing) from the NTinternals guys.  I've been migrating that binary around for maybe a decade, and it still works.  Their company got assimilated by Microsoft, but the binaries are still hanging around on the net if you search.

Answer (score 1):

Get the current day, month and year into environment variables (adjust for locale).

Command line:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %a in ('echo %date%') do set mon=%a && set day=%b && set year=%c
```

Or in a batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do set mon=%%a && set day=%%b && set year=%%c
```

---

Other stuff

`ipconfig /displaydns`

`WMIC` - command line access to WMI

`dsqery`, `dsget`, `dsmod`, `dsadd` - command line access to AD

`net localgroup`

`for /f %%a (' some command ') do call :sub %%a`

Use `::` instead of `REM` in batch files.

`nbtstat`

`NTRIGHTS.EXE  grant sePriveleges`

Set /P for prompting.

`IF ELSE` in batch:

```
IF EXIST filename. (
    del filename.
) ELSE (
    echo filename. missing.
)
```

Comment: Thanks for ipocnfig /displaydns, I did not know about that one. It seems like it could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
httpcfg [query | set | delete] iplisten [ip address]
```

to find out or change the IP addresses [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) is listening on

(If you want to run IIS and some other HTTP server on the same box and port with different IP addresses.)

Answer (score 1):

I've found Launchy to be a very useful tool for Windows.  It lets you launch many programs that would normally be launched by clicking icons by typing a few keystrokes.  There's also a version for Linux.  It can be found at www.launchy.net, and is free and open-source.

For example, to open an Explorer window from anywhere, type Alt-space (the default Launchy hot-key) followed by "c:\" followed by Enter.  You can run any program for which you have a Windows shortcut by typing a few characters from the name of the shortcut.  For example: Alt-space "co" Enter brings up Control Panel.  You can also do Google searches, open URLs in the browser, and many other things without taking your fingers from the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

**[psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)**

While it's from [Sysinternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals), the sysinternals tools are so essential and commonly installed on servers they might as well be part of the OS.

```
psexec \\targetserver -w "d:\bin" "cmd"
```

You now have an interactive shell on a remote computer. Enter "exit" to come back home. I will often use it to apply something to a group of servers as follows.

```
set srvs=server1 server2 server3 
set execthis=[something useful]
for %s IN (%srvs%) DO (
start psexec \%s -u domain\someUser -p superSecretOfCourse "cmd" "/C %execthis%" 
)
```

Here I show several handy tricks:

1. Use for loops to execute a command multiple times (from batch use %%s instead of %s)
2. **Start** to open a window in a new process - handy if each operations takes a few minutes.
3. Psexec can use windows auth or a login. Noting that integrated auth usually won't hop from local to server to a third location (e.g. SAN) - provide user and password if you need to access a network resource

Answer (score 1):

```
bootsect.exe {/help | /nt52 | /nt60} {SYS | ALL | <DriveLetter:>} [/force]
```

From *[Bootsect Command-Line Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749177(WS.10).aspx)*:

> Bootsect.exe updates the master boot code for hard disk partitions to switch between BOOTMGR and NTLDR. You can use this tool to restore the boot sector on your computer.

Mind you that this tool is only available on the Windows installation DVD under the **`BOOT`** folder. (I think only Windows Vista or higher.)

Answer (score 1):

[FTP](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

dsa.msc - opens active directory users and computers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBScript that will do elevation when you RUNAS in Vista:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
app = wscript.arguments(0)
args = ""
for i = 1 to (WScript.Arguments.length - 1)
   args = args + wscript.arguments(i)
next
objShell.ShellExecute app, args, "", "runas"
```

Use like so:
runas.exe /user:domain\user "wscript.exe runas_script.vbs mmc.exe"

Answer (score 1):

The following web site shows how to create command line shortcuts to anything using the Windows registry key, "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths".

Customizing Windows Run Command
http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/04/11/111232.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
at
```

Gives you a way to schedule tasks either locally or remotely without using Scheduled Tasks.

```
Running a command every Friday

AT 23:30 /EVERY:f c:\backups\weekly.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

When starting the services control panel for the first time, on a fresh install;

```
services.msc /a
```

then choose the "standard"-tab, move the description column all the way to the right, and then `File -> Save` the new layout.

Answer (score 1):

Query Domain Controllers @ netdom /query /domain:MyDomainName fsmo

Answer (score 1):

- pushd/popd to move around directories in a stack style
- ldp.exe - all the LDAP/AD power at your fingertips
- nltest.exe - the swiss army knife of domains and trusts

Comment: pushd/popd proved to be quite useful...

Answer (score 1):

```
getmac
```

shows the [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of any network adapters installed.

Comment: Thanks, justingrif but this has already been posted - http://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/3864#3864

Answer (score 1):

```
perfmon
```

Opens up **Windows Performance Monitor**.

Answer (score 1):

The   key combination . . . notepad  will show all files in the directory, use the up and down key to select, then enter to execute the command.  Very useful for lazy typers like myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
whoami /all
```

Used to be reskit.

Answer (score 1):

**qfecheck**
for Server 2003,2000 & XP - Does not apply to Server 2008, Vista or Win7(as far as I know)

Shows installed Hotfixes applied to the server/workstation.

More detail at -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282784

Answer (score 1):

vssadmin

```
Usage:

vssadmin list shadows [/set={shadow copy set guid}]
        Lists all shadow copies in the system, grouped by shadow copy set Id.

vssadmin list writers
        Lists all writers in the system

vssadmin list providers
        Lists all currently installed shadow copy providers
```

vssadmin is essential to troubleshooting backup products that use vss. With vssadmin you can check writer status, and list all outstanding shadow copies on a volume.  Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

I particularly like `pushd` and `popd` for directory navigation via stack.  Not only can they change the current folder, they can also change the current drive.  (`cd /d` can do this too.)  What's more, if you try to `pushd` to a UNC path, the shell will automatically map the share to a drive letter starting from `Z` and working backwards.  When the matching `popd` is called, the drive is unmapped automatically.

Answer (score 1):

A particularly useful aspect of netsh that I think is worth a mention:
netsh winsock reset
This was added in XP service pack 2 to reset the tcpip implementation back to its defaults.  In versions prior to XP, this was accomplished by uninstalling and reinstalling TCP/IP.  Prior to SP2 you either needed the winsockxpfix.exe application or an ugly method of ripping out tcp/ip and reinstalling it.  This command can correct issues where tcp/ip becomes corrupted for whatever reason.

Also, the HELP command lists a whole slew of other commands that can be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Change {username}'s password:

```
net user {username} {newpass}
```

map a network drive

```
net use z: \\servername\sharename /user:username
```

Answer (score 1):

1. ***mspaint***

[image]

2. ***msconfig***  :-System Configuration Utility
   [image]

*3. **ping ip address***
[image]

4.***textpad***

[image]

5.***sshclient***
[image]

6.***%temp%***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Command to abort the shutdown process.

c:\shutdown -a

Answer (score 1):

print %logonserver% 
A very quick and easy way to view the DC that your workstation has authenticated against. Useful when working with GPO's and scripts.

Comment: `PRINT`? Not `ECHO`?

Answer (score 0):

**Telephone and Modem Properties**

The command

```
telephon.cpl
```

opens

[image]

**Side Note**: I wish I never get to see this screen ever again...

Comment: great +1... very very usefull

Comment: It made me shiver...

Answer (score 0):

It is always fun to create a macro that performs a quick and unconditional format of a disk:

```
doskey cd=format $1 /q /u
```

Then to format a disk in drive A type:

```
cd A:
```

Comment: Shame they dropped the format's /autotest parameter. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of

```
newsid
```

Comment: If you're still using newsid, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

powercfg.exe /QUERY

> Description:
>     This command line tool enables an administrator to control
>      the power settings on a system.

powercfg.exe /? for full command list

Answer (score 0):

```
devenv   # to start visual studio IDE.
```

Answer (score 0):

MSINFO32

```
MSINFO32.EXE

Msinfo32 [/?] [/pch] [/nfo Path] [/report Path] [/computer ComputerName] [/showcategories] [/category categoryID] [/categories categoryID]
```

Between this, the event log and the Problem Steps Recorder, you can usually get the critical support data in just a few keystrokes.

When I am skeptical of user-reported information, I often have them run the following and e-mail me the output:

```
msinfo32 /report %userprofile%\Desktop\sysinfo.txt
```

Or just:

```
msinfo32
```

Then:

```
File > Export
```

Answer (score 0):

A little known one is `eventtriggers`.

The windows task scheduler has a hidden way to schedule programs to run when particular events occur in one of the windows event logs. These kinds of tasks can only be configured from the eventtriggers command. It works in a very similar way to `schtasks`.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490901.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted somthing simular - I have a modified version.

I create a desktop shortcut to logoff.exe and place in allusers/desktop on all servers. This way when you are done with your RDP sesssion, you just double click the logoff icon!

Love it!

Answer (score 0):

Except for [BGInfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557) with my custom configuration file, this is the best thing I've deployed to the domain via group policy:

```
elevate
```

It does exactly that; it elevates whatever command you run at the command prompt so that you don't need to have explicitly started an elevated command prompt, nor have to run everything in elevated mode. It still brings up the UAC prompt, but I find it useful when I've had a command prompt running most of the day that has the commands I've used in it, but then need to quickly add a route, or do something that requires elevation without losing my history and starting a new `cmd`.

As I said, I deployed it via group policy (into `%windir%\system32`) and got it from [John Robbin at Wintellect](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/03/27/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`shadow` will allow you to shadow someone's RDP or Terminal Server session. Very useful for troubleshooting a box remotely with another party:

```
query user
shadow SESSIONNAME
```

A `Control` + `*` will stop the shadowing the session.

Answer (score 0):

I use 'set' from a command line quite a lot when wanting to find the system environment variables. Such as whether or not an end users machine is 64bit.

> set
>
> Type SET without parameters to display the current environment
>   variables.