# WTS - Remote list connected users

Tags: windows, remote

Some times, remote users don't disconnect and new connections fails with this message: 
The terminal server has exceeded the maximum number of allowed connections.

How can I list connected users remotelly to ask him for disconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here [Useful Command-line Commands on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows/4203#4203)

Comment: quser /SERVER:myserver

Comment: Does not provide ipaddresses or hostnames of connected users

Answer (score 2):

You could use this nice little command line tool:

http://home.fnal.gov/~jklemenc/tslistusers.html

> TSListUsers is a command line utility
>   to list both the currently connected
>   and disconnected users, hostname, IP
>   address and RDP session number on
>   either the local or a remote Windows
>   Terminal Server/RDP Server To list the
>   users, you need to have the following
>   abilities:
>   - NetBios access to the server
>   - Permissions allowing you to Query RDP session information (if you can
>   log into the TS, you should have this
>   by default)
>   - Terminal Services/RDP should be running on the target host
>
> Usage:
>
> - TSListUsers.exe /? to get the Help
>     text
> - TSListUsers.exe to query a
>     target Terminal Server
> - TSListUsers.exe with no paramters to
>     query the local host

Comment: +1 Fantastic for me because I got computer hostnames and everything (essential since we share a single user on the controlled computer)

Answer (score 1):

Use *qwinsta* (Query Windows Station) to list the sessions and usernames of your local or a remote terminal services host.

You can then also use *rwinsta* to disconnect or log off a session of your choice (given the permission to do so).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the same network you can install the server 2003 (or 2008) admin tools on your machine which will give you access to terminal services managment console, you can then connect to the server with that and see the logged on and disconnected users.

Alternatively if you need to get on the server, you can use the console access method in RDP. Just use this command from the run window:

```
mstsc /v:serverIP /admin
```

Once logged on to the console, you can open up the terminal services management console and see who is logged in and disconnect them.

Bear in mind that if anyone is currently logged into the console, either remotely or at the server, it will disconnect them.

Comment: I know /admin switch. But I need to know who, before disconnect him.

Comment: So are you saying remote users are logging onto the console via RDP? If they are using normal RDP sessions you can login through the console (so not logging them off), then open up Terminal Services Manager (Its in administrative tools), and see who is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system is this with?  If you're using Windows 2003 Server or Windows 2008 Server and you have console access to the machine, you can see the currently logged in users under the 'Users' tab in Task Manager.

Comment: I don't have this access. The server is in another city.