# Rename an account from XP command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line-interface, user-management, rename

How can I rename a local user account from the XP command prompt?

Is there a `NET.EXE` personality that I've missed?  (I also didn't see anything under [Useful Commandline Commands on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows).)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my research, NET USER cannot rename a local user account. Domain accounts can be renamed at a command line with dsmod, but that is of no use to you. You must use either a vbscript to do this or a special utility such as renuser.exe (which I can't find a link to).

Link to a VBScript that might be of use to you: http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/microsoft.public.windowsxp.security_admin/2003-05/0596.html