# Windows command line "suspend"

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, suspend

**On Windows, there's the [shutdown](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-windows-commands/4987#4987) cmd line, but is there a windows command line command to call a "standby"?**

**What I'd really like is to call something like `standby -force` to force a system to enter standby even when a pesky app is trying to prevent it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState

The action will differ depending on whether or not you have Hibernation enabled.

Documentation on SetSuspendState:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate

Answer (score 2):

PSshutdown, part of the free PSTools suite from the Sysinternals team at Microsoft, can do this. Shutdown.exe on my XP machine will not - you have not told us what version of Windows you're asking about, and I don't know if shutdown.exe has that option on Vista or different Server versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Vista and 7 you can use the /h switch of the shutdown command to hibernate the computer and /f to force the command: shutdown /h /f.