# Is there a tool akin to 'who' or 'w' via the command-line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

Without using something like cygwin, is there a way to find out everyone who is logged-into a Windows server form the command-line?

Comment: I did not see anything like it listed here: http://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`who`:

```
qwinsta
query station
```

---

`w`, `finger`:

```
quser
query user
```

---

It is possible to write a custom tool using [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838%28VS.85%29.aspx) - very easy to use via [Python with PyWin32](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32ts.html):

```
import win32ts
protocols = {
    win32ts.WTS_PROTOCOL_TYPE_CONSOLE: "console",
    win32ts.WTS_PROTOCOL_TYPE_ICA: "citrix",
    win32ts.WTS_PROTOCOL_TYPE_RDP: "rdp",
}

## alternatively, hServer = win32ts.WTSOpenServer("hostname")
hServer = win32ts.WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE

currentSessId = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
for session in win32ts.WTSEnumerateSessions(hServer):
    sessionId = session["SessionId"]
    session["UserName"] = win32ts.WTSQuerySessionInformation(hServer, sessionId, win32ts.WTSUserName)
    session["WinStationName"] = session["WinStationName"] or "(disconnected)"
    session["Protocol"] = win32ts.WTSQuerySessionInformation(hServer, sessionId, win32ts.WTSClientProtocolType)
    session["ProtocolName"] = protocols.get(session["Protocol"], "unknown")
    print "%(UserName)-20s %(WinStationName)s (%(ProtocolName)s/%(SessionId)d)" % session
```

Comment: I think you mean `query session` and not `query station`?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
WMIC /Node:remotecomputer ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

For example

```
WMIC /Node:127.0.0.1 ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

More information:

- an article on [Microsoft TechNet about WMIC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx)
- a [blog post comparing WMIC with Windows Powershell Cmdlets for WMI](http://blogs.msdn.com/wmi/archive/2010/01/06/wmic-vs-wmi-powershell-cmdlets.aspx).

Comment: Nice.  Have not heard of WMIC.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Microsofts Sysinternals tool [PSLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

type in `query user` or `query user /server:remoteserver` for a list of currently logged in users.  This will also tell you how they are logged in.  This works on standalone servers and workstations as well as terminal servers

Comment: Can you post a link to some documentation?

Comment: Dennis the docs are here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_queryuser.mspx?mfr=true There is just a bit more there than query /?. I use qwinsta more often.