# map a drive through NET USE command

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, mappeddrive, net-use

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Useful Command-line Commands on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows)

we need to mape a network folder on 2008server and client is XP; we want to use the command line on windows XP

Answer (score 4):

Net use [drive letter] [unc path]

example:

```
net use z: \\servername\share$
```

Comment: Why the $ ?  I don't believe it is a requirement, but you can use it to create "hidden" share, correct?

Comment: Yes, the "$" is for hidden resources.

Answer (score 3):

the syntax is `Net Use x: \\servername\sharename`.  X can be replaced with drive letter not already in use.  If a drive letter is already in use and you need to reuse it, try `Net use x: /del` to remove the mapping first.

Answer (score 1):

"network folder on 2008server and client is XP"

If the XP account is different from the 2008 (server) account, then the "/user:[username]" option should also be included.

`net use [drive letter] \\[servername]\[sharename] /user:[username]`

It will then prompt for the password of the remote user on the server.