# how to add run date on a .bat file without adding it in Task Scheduler

Tags: schedule

I created a .bat file to delete some files inside the installer folder.
My question is how can I make it schedule without using task scheduler.

is there any other way or script for this?

**example code:**
forfiles /p "path" /m *.config* /c "cmd /c del @path"

Comment: Schedule without using task scheduler? Well, you can install an alternative to a task scheduler. But why?

Comment: Just to make it silent run without accessing the task scheduler. Is it possible in a script?

Comment: [Of course.](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows/11548#11548) Or you could just run it without the task scheduler when you need it.

Comment: Actually, this will be run on another device so that's why I need to run it on a schedule